# Upload picture in custom register form

Tags: forms, users, media

I'm building a multistep register form in a custom module. I'm using profile2 module to save other custom fields. I want to let the users choose an image from their computers. This is the code that I use to upload the picture that saves in the file_managed Drupal table but without the user uid because at this point I don't create the user.

```
$form['empresa']['logo_empresa'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Logo de la empresa.'),
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#description' => t('Tamaño máximo 3Mb y formato aceptado jpg,jpeg o png'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('png jpg jpeg'),
        'file_validate_size' => array(3*300*300),
        ),
);
```

When all fields are OK I submit the form and create the user as follows:

```
function empresas_registration_signup_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {


$nombre = $form_state['storage']['field_nombre_contacto'];
$apellidos = $form_state['storage']['field_apellidos_contacto'];
$mail = $form_state['storage']['email'];
$comunidad_autonoma = $form_state['storage']['field_comunidad_autonoma'];

$provincias = $form_state['storage']['field_provincia'];
$razon_social = $form_state['storage']['field_razon_social'];
$cif_nif = $form_state['storage']['field_cif_dni'];
$telefono = $form_state['storage']['field_telefono'];
$web = $form_state['storage']['field_web'];

$municipios = $form_state['storage']['field_municipio'];
$poblacion = $form_state['storage']['field_poblacion'];
$direccion = $form_state['storage']['field_direccion'];
$codigo_postal = $form_state['storage']['field_codigo_postal'];

$razon_social = $form_state['storage']['field_razon_social'];   
$clave = substr($razon_social, 0, 3);
$cif_nif = $form_state['storage']['field_cif_dni'];

$usuario = $clave.$cif_nif;
$password = password(8);
//$imagen = $form_state['values']['field_logo_empresa'];

$roles = user_roles();
$newuser = array(
        'name' => $usuario,
        'pass' => $password,
        'mail' => $mail,
        'status' => 1,
        'roles' => array('7' => 'empresa'),
        'access' => time(),

);
$existing_user = user_load($usuario);
if (!$existing_user->uid) {
    $account = user_save(null, $newuser);

    $profile = entity_create('profile2', array('type' => 'empresa'));
    $profile->uid = $account->uid;

    //Datos a guardar para el perfil

    $profile->field_nombre_contacto[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $nombre;
    $profile->field_apellidos_contacto[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $apellidos;
    $profile->field_razon_social[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $razon_social;
    $profile->field_cif_dni[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $cif_nif;
    $profile->field_direccion[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $direccion;
    $profile->field_codigo_postal[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $codigo_postal;
    $profile->field_telefono[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $telefono;
    $profile->field_web[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $web;
    $profile->field_poblacion[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $poblacion;
    $profile->field_comunidad_autonoma[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $comunidad_autonoma;
    $profile->field_provincia[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $provincias;
    $profile->field_municipio[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $municipios;

    $profile->save();

    $account->profiles['empresa'] = $profile;
    entity_save('user', $account);
    drupal_goto('user');

}
}
```

My question is: How could I set the fid from the table and assign it to the user?

Comment: Any reason not to use image field?

Comment: You could create an image field in your entity type and attach it to your form with field_attach_form() or create a table and on form submission write fid to that table.

Comment: @Mołot I've used $form_state['storage']['logo_empresa'] = ($form_state['values']['logo_empresa']); but nothing happens. Managed file saves the file in the table that's all. I'm quite new in Drupal so, How could I save the file in my form?

Answer (score 1):

@Luism, you should use field widget for it. `field_attach_form` attaches fields to form, `field_attach_form_validate` validates all attached fields, `field_attach_submit` prepared entity to be stored. Regarding values in `$form_state['values']` you will have big structure inside `$form_state['values']['FIELD_NAME'][LANGUAGE][INDEX]` but you need only `$form_state['values']['FIELD_NAME'][LANGUAGE][INDEX]['fid']`, it will contain File ID from file_managed table (with status=0) for uploaded files and after `profile2_save()` file will be activated or deleted otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please give me a tutorial link usage or something like that to see how put this in my custom form?

Comment: Something like this [code](http://pastebin.com/SHdvpfi6)